# Help with windows path - PHP

Tags: php

I have this path and it is correct however, the browser will not include the source file unless I put "file:///" in front of it. I'm still developing and this will ultimately be on a Linux machine but in the mean time, I'd like to see my work as well as be able to troubleshoot it. Is there a solution for this?

This fails:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\work\site\js\rowlock.js
```

This does not fail:

```
file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\work\site\js\rowlock.js
```

Comment: can you name the specific command you're issuing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to make your script independent. For example:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/js/rowlock.js');
```

Works fine on any system

Comment: This is what I think I'm going to have to use after all. Thanks.

Comment: @Silver Light, the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does'nt work on Windows IIS & CGI & Apache VirtualHost!

Answer (score 10):

just use front slashes everywhere if you'll be moving this to a linux box anyway. php for windows can understand it.

```
$file='c:/Program Files (x86)/work/site/js/rowlock.js';
```

Comment: Rockjock, I am currently using forward slashes but the file still won't load. The only way I can get the file to load os by putting "file:// in front of the "C:\"

Comment: right, but the debugging right now is on a winbox so we need to isolate the problem

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around your path. You have spaces, so it is not read correctly.

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\work\site\js\rowlock.js'
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have already tried that and get "Illegal url" in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Where is Your root folder?

If its 
C:\Program Files (x86)\work\site\

Then simple access your file like this

js/rowlock.js

This assuming that js is in the Root folder

Comment: I was hoping to use the absolute path so that if I ever wanted to change the directory structure, it wouldn't be that big of a deal.